# Unable to display image in django when the url is correct

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django. In my app, I'm working on an image uploading and displaying function. I have tried setting up the `MEDIA_URL` and `Media_ROOT`. I also add the static path to the `urls.py` file and make sure that in HTML template `object.image.url` is used. However, the image is not displayed. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit 1 (Add project structure):

This is a screenshot of my project structure:
[link to my project structure screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mosW.png)

Edit 2 (Add screenshots of browser):
[link to browser screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXz6U.png)

[django admin page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VtBt.png)

[the image in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Y0Yn.png)

Edit 3 (Add screenshot of browser inspect window)
[image of browser inspect window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QI07O.png)

My code is as followed:

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("auctions.urls"))
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

views.py

```
class ListingForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ListingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in iter(self.fields):
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({
                'class': 'form-control'
        })

    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'current_price', 'image', 'category']

def index(request):
    return render(request, "auctions/index.html", {
        "active_listings" : Listing.objects.all()
    })

def createListing(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        listing_data = ListingForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if listing_data.is_valid():
            title = listing_data['title']
            description = listing_data.cleaned_data['description']
            current_price = listing_data.cleaned_data['current_price']
            if listing_data.cleaned_data['image']:
                image = listing_data.cleaned_data['image']
            else:
                image = None
            category = listing_data.cleaned_data['category']
            listing = Listing(title=title, description=description, current_price=current_price, image=image, category=category)
            listing.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
    return render(request, "auctions/createListing.html", {
        "listingForm" : ListingForm()
    })
```

models.py

```
class Listing(models.Model):

    class Category(models.TextChoices):
        FASHION = 'FA', _('Fashion')
        TOYS = 'TO', _('Toys')
        ELECTRONICS = 'EL', _('Electronics')
        HOME = 'HO', _('Home')
        OTHERS = 'OT', _('Others')

    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField()
    current_price = models.IntegerField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='listingImages', blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, choices=Category.choices)
```

settings.py

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

index.html

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h2>Active Listings</h2>

    <ul>
        {% for listing in active_listings %}
        <li>Title: {{ listing.title }}</li>
        <li>Description: {{ listing.description }}</li>
        <li>Current Price: {{ listing.current_price }}</li>
        {% if listing.image %}
        <li>
            <img scr="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ listing.image.url }}" alt="{{ listing.image.url }}">
        </li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
   
{% endblock %}
```

createListing.html

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
<h1>Create A New Listing</h1>
    <form action="{% url 'createListing' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in listingForm %}
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ field.label }} {{ field }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" value="Done">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `src` attribute in your `img` tag from this:

```
scr="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ listing.image.url }}"
```

to this:

```
scr="{{ listing.image.url }}"
```

Also you can try to add a line like this to check if image exists at all:

```
{% if listing.image %}
    <li>
        <img scr="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ listing.image.url }}" alt="{{ listing.image.url }}">
    </li>
{% else %} 
    <p> Image doesnt exist. </p>
{% endif %}
```

**UPDATE**

Try making your main `urls.py` like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("auctions.urls"))
] 

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Instead of what you have right now.